# Issues with Change Password function

Tags: c#

Having some issues with some of my code that has brought me to a brick wall.  Even after searching a few hours I cant seem to get it to work.  I am quite new to c# so any advice at all even if it points me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

What's odd is that it is correctly looping through the dataset,  however when it finds the correct row.ItemArray[0].Equals(changeUserName) it does not continue the code and instead skips past it to the "Change failed" error, wont even show the messagebox!

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is this:

There is a table with 3 Columns.  Username Password and Email.  Password Column contains Hashed Passwords.

I have a form with 4 labels and 4 text fields:

1. Username - changeusername Textbox
2. Current Password - currentpassword Textbox
3. New Password - newpassword Text box
4. Confirm New Password - confirmnewpassword Text Box

The user fills these forms in, then hits the Change Password Button, which starts the below function:

(This function should check the value of username text box (and current password once ran through my HashPass Function) and compare them to the values in the dataset.  If it finds matching values,  It then should change the Password value to the new password value in newpassword Text Box.  However it does not do this and I cannot figure out why!)

Note: Some of the code in  //And look for matching usernames is commented out as I was just trying to get it to even show a MessageBox once it finds a matching Username.  But it would not even do this!

```
public void changePass(string changeusername, string old, string new1, string confirmnew)
{
    string EncryptedPass = HashPass(new1);

    //If there is no username
    if (changeusername == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Username!");
        return;
    }

    //Confirm new pass must equal confirmnewpassword.
    else if (new1 != confirmnew)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("New Passwords do not match");
    }
    bool loop = false;
    //loop database and update new password
    foreach (DataRow row in <nameremoved>stockDataSet.login)
    {
        //And look for matching usernames
        if (row.ItemArray[0].Equals(changeUserName))
        { 
            //row.ItemArray[1] = EncryptedPass;
            MessageBox.Show("Change Success");
            loop = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //Catch Error if Failure

    if (loop == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Change Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run through with a debugger to see what the values(s) of `row.ItemArray[0]` are?

Comment: If the new passwords don't match you show a message box and then continue execution, so even if they don't match it'll change the password. You should either `return` afterwards or wrap the rest of the code in an else block.

Comment: yep!,  The item array contains username, hashed password and email for each row it loops through,  What is very strange is,  I just tried a different username.  It found that username and gave me the "change success" messagebox.  However it did not change the password when i de-commented the row.itemarray[1] = EncryptedPass.  So something weird is going on  


Also, Eitamal, I did not know this!,  Yes that would be quite a bad thing to happen.  thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: check casing. `Username` is not equal to `username` or `userName`...

Comment: Try converting username to lowercase and then compare it, like this: `if (row[0].ToString().ToLower().Equals(changeUserName.ToLower()))`

Comment: some of the casing was indeed wrong,  seems to be a very easy mistake to make, I will aim to be more vigilant in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change a single item inside the item array using the indexer.
This happens because when you try to access the ItemArray property, a copy of the original array is created and returned to your code.
And you change items in this copy not on the original one.

You need to get the item array returned, change it and assign it back to the ItemArray property

```
foreach (DataRow row in <nameremoved>stockDataSet.login)
{
    //And look for matching usernames
    if (row.ItemArray[0].Equals(changeUserName))
    { 
        object[] returnedArray = row.ItemArray;
        returnedArray[1] = EncryptedPass;
        row.ItemArray = returnedArray;
        MessageBox.Show("Change Success");
        loop = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

You can check this behavior looking at the [Reference Source of ItemArray](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,c49b336f59c8f808)

However, I can't understand why you want to use the ItemArray property in this context. You can simply refer to your row/column using the standard syntax or better use the Select method on the DataTable to find your row

```
DataRow[] found = login.Select($"userName = '{changeUserName}'");
if(found != null && found.Length > 0)
{
    found[0]["Password"] = EncryptedPass;
}
```

Here I assume that your first column is named *userName* and you second column is named *Password* (change them to fit your names)

Comment: his code doesn't enter the block which updates row :). @Exxili, you should your `changeUserName` variable (is it in right case?). And, regarding this, solution, simplier code would be just to avoid ItemArray, and use `if (row[0].Equals(changeUserName) { row[1] = new1; }`

Comment: Hey Steve.  This helped me immensely thank you.!  and you too Nino, it was because of the incorrect case of some values that it failed to enter the block.

Comment: Nino,  Could i then change the {row[1] = Hashpass(new1); }?  That way it would compare the two hashes and not the text password?

Comment: Yes, you should definitively store the hashed password and not the clear one